# what is hard reference in java?

Tags: java

When I was studying about permgen, I came across the term hard reference. I don't know what is meant by hard reference. Can anyone explain or give me some tutorials about that please?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of tutorials of hard (aka strong) and weak references in java

- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references
- http://www.coderanch.com/t/433742/java/java/WeakReference-hard-reference-scope-JIT

<sub>Found by simple googling</sub>

Comment: Yep - don't reinvent the tutorial :)

Answer (score 2):

Hard references are normal references, i.e. variables, as opposed to subclasses of [java.lang.ref.Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html), phantom, soft, and weak references.

Answer (score 1):

A strong (hard) reference is a reference that tells the garbage collector not to touch this object (as in, not removing it from memory).

Any object reachable trough strong references from a garbage collector root (Temporary variables on the stack (of any thread), Static variables (from any class) and Special references from JNI native code) will be kept alive. Strong references are normal references.

Soft references, Weak references, and Phantom references are not considered by the garbage collector when cleaning up (this is not completely true, as Soft references are kept for some amount of time).
Any object that is only reachable trough non-strong references might be cleaned up during the execution of your program, and these references can return `null` at any given time. Opposite to strong references, you need to make a [referenceobject](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html) to use these type of references.

For more background on soft, weak and phantom references, look at [this document](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html).